# How to move SVN branch/s to GIT branch

Tags: git, svn

I'm new to GIT and recently we moved our project from SVN to GIT. While moving the code-base we created GIT master repository from SVN TRUNK repo and left rest of code-base in SVN as it is. Meantime we have been creating new branches from GIT master repo and working in them for past few days. But, recently we observed that one or more of SVN branches (which we left earlier) also need to be moved to GIT and they will be merged later in GIT master repo for final release. Is there any easier way to move those SVN branches to GIT ? Please suggest ?

Thanks in advance. 
Reddy

Comment: You would have been better of starting with `--stdlayout` (or custom) as in the [git-svn documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). But: nothing prevents you from starting a git branch, checking out an svn branch there, and pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git).

> svn2git is a tiny utility for migrating projects from Subversion to Git while keeping the trunk, branches and tags where they should be.

And all the conversion is done in one step, like:

```
svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo
```

For detail please refer to its [github page](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git).